# how to store time and date values in sq Lite and manipulate them?

Tags: android

I am working on a android application where i need to offer a prize to the user and it should expire in 24 hours and that reducing  time should be displayed in my app.and i need to store the prize offer time in sq Lite and that time should reduced to 24 hours to 0 hours can any one help me out of how to do this?

Comment: sore your date as string & use SimpleDateFormat for convert it to date

Comment: Why do you want to store data in sqlite? Cant you use aimple java variables?

Answer (score 0):

Use this tutorial.. save date as VARCHAR and and after retrieving convert it into date object.

[dis](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think convertion data to `Integer`(SQLite data type) is the best way to store date in SQLite because it make comparision easier(using SQL query) than when storing date as text. If You are using `java.util.Date` use method `getTime()` to get time in miliseconds and store that value in database.